# rasterio with Earthdata login

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, authentication

A lot of remote sensing imagery from the USGS and NASA is hosted behind an Earthdata login account (which is free). I'd like to be able to open the files directly using rasterio and passing along my credentials. I can do this with fsspec. But I'd  like to use only rasterio with the built in gdal authentication option, which is not working.

So the  following works:

```
import rasterio, fsspec, aiohttp

username, password = 'earthdata_login', 'earthdata_pw!'

tif_file = 'https://data.lpdaac.earthdatacloud.nasa.gov/lp-prod-protected/HLSS30.020/HLS.S30.T55JCN.2015332T001732.v2.0/HLS.S30.T55JCN.2015332T001732.v2.0.B07.tif'

with fsspec.open(tif_file, client_kwargs={'auth': aiohttp.BasicAuth(username, password)}) as fobj:
    with rasterio.open(fobj) as src:
        print(src.profile)
```

But the following gives an IO error.

```
with rasterio.Env(GDAL_HTTP_AUTH = 'BASIC', GDAL_HTTP_USERPWD = f'{username}:{password}'):
    with rasterio.open(tif_file) as src:
        print(src.profile)
```

How can I open files with rasterio using the GDAL authentication option?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of:

1. [Create a token](https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/documentation/for_users/user_token)
2. [Use a .netrc file](https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/documentation/for_users/data_access/curl_and_wget)

Both of which I prefer to keeping secrets in the code (e.g. `username, password = 'earthdata_login', 'earthdata_pw!'` ) as there's much less chance of accidentally committing them to a public repository like GitHub.

For 1. hdr.txt contains:

```shell
Authorization: Bearer edfkjdfsdlkfSdlkfjSLDkfsldkf?SLDKfm?SDKfm?SLDKfmetc...etc...
```

Code:

```py
with rio.Env(GDAL_HTTP_HEADER_FILE="hdr.txt"):
    with rio.open(tif_file) as src:
        print(src.profile)
```

Output:

```sh
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'int16', 'nodata': -9999.0, 'width': 3660, 'height': 3660, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32655), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 300000.0,
       0.0, -30.0, -2700000.0), 'blockxsize': 256, 'blockysize': 256, 'tiled': True, 'compress': 'deflate', 'interleave': 'band'}
```

For 2. .netrc contains:

```sh
machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login some_user password ABCdef123!
```

Code:

```py
with rio.open(tif_file) as src:
    print(src.profile)
```

Output:

```sh
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'int16', 'nodata': -9999.0, 'width': 3660, 'height': 3660, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32655), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 300000.0,
       0.0, -30.0, -2700000.0), 'blockxsize': 256, 'blockysize': 256, 'tiled': True, 'compress': 'deflate', 'interleave': 'band'}
```